# Periodically update a table with new records from another server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have databases on two different servers. I need to regularly retrieve new records from a table on server A, and process them in order to use them to update a table on server B (with a different schema). I was going to use a trigger for this, but if this fails, the inserts on server A are rolled back. The inserts on table A must not fail, so the update of server B needs to be as decoupled from this as possible. I am now thinking of using a scheduled sproc on server B to retrieve the results from server A and update server B. This would need to run every 30 seconds. Is there anything wrong with this approach, or is there a better or more 'correct' way of achieving this?

Comment: You are looking for replication.Also possible with jobs or windows services.

Comment: you need to have a linked server to serverB inside serverA and update serverB through it. you may need a replication or mirroring, it's better to ask it on [dba.stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com) you'll get great answers, here most of users are developers not dba

Comment: There will a 30 seconds data gap between your two serves, it's ok if you don't mind. You can also try catch in your trigger to prevent rollback. Or search SQL Server Replication for more robust way to keep servers synchronized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think creating a scheduled job in SQL Server Agent is the way to go here. This can execute a simple stored procedure (if the logic is realatively simple) or an SSIS package (where it is more complex).

Just a final note on triggers: if possible I have always tried to avoid using triggers. They can have what appear to be "unintended" or "mysterious" side effects, they can be difficult to debug and developers can often forget to check for triggers when trying to resolve an issue. That's not to say they don't offer benfits too - but I think you need to be wary of them.